Getting the working directory when code is running in a docker image in a github action
So I am running a typescript project using a simple dockerfile. In my typescript I call const ROOT = process.cwd() to get the root and then look for a config file there. When this is executed by code running in a docker container in a github workflow process.cwd() returns the root of the github runner not the docker container. I have a solution to this which is just to exactly specifify the file path but am looking for a more robust solution. I am wondering if there is somthing like a env value I could use?
Here is the dockerfile
FROM node:20-slim

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/dist/index.js"]



Using process.env.CONFIG_FILE in your code, and Dockerfile ENV CONFIG_FILE=... or docker run -e CONFIG_FILE=..., seems a little more robust.

So that would work for a project where I know the file structure. However, I would like my code to be able to be run as a package in other projects. In that case I won't know the exact path to the config file, only that it will be in the root of the project

If you're writing a library, I'd take the path to the config file as a parameter.  I would not assume anything about the filesystem layout where the containing application will eventually be run.

So I am trying to make a file similar to something like tsconfig.json. So its a JSON file in the root of the npm project. Although you might be right and it may be worth re working my code to accept it as a input
